# Wix import xml with common directory

Tags: xml, wix

I have a couple of setup files (wxs). The all have something in common. Let me explain by example:

```
<Fragment>
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder" Name="PFiles">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="MyApp">
           <Component Id="BaseComponent" Guid="667DD08A-967D-47FD-BE4A-CCD866E2B187">
              <File Source="two.dll" />
              <File Source="three.dll" />
              <!-- Total of about fourty files -->
              <File Source="fourty.dll" />

           </Component>
           <Directory Id="MODULES" Name="Module">
              <Component Id="MODULESComponent" Guid="F74980CB-8480-473A-A897-AB4C5DA67E54">
                 <File Source="a" />
                 <File Source="b" />
                 <File Source="c" />
              </Component>
           </Directory>
        </Directory>
     </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Fragment>
```

This fragment is copied into multiple setups. With the exception that the Name-"MyApp" is for every copy different, and the Guid of the 'BaseComponent' is different per setup.

And.... the directory with id 'Modules' is also different per setup!!!

I did look at the fragment solution (wixlib), but because of the MODULES that is different in every setup, i think this will not work.

The problem of the MyApp name, and the Guid might be solved with using variables in the different setups.

But how do I get the Component part (BaseComponent) into a seperate file, and import it into multiple other files???

Answer (score 0):

Just took a better look at the c# templates for Wix Setup, and found the Include file. This I can use. So the solution is to use the Include wxi files.